# Visual Basic .Net GUI

Tags: vb.net, user-interface

so i made a full project with vb.net , which contains some form and a lot of buttons ..... etc

now i wanna make a gui selecting option
but the problem is that , i don't wanna go to each single button and change it , and go to every single form and change the background color and stuff

is there anyway to change the whole gui by simple method ?
example > change all button to black button , and all form background color to black ?

or shall i do them manually one by one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your form designer.
Drag select (i.e. start top left corner, mouse down, drag) all the controls you'd like to change.
Once they're selected, set the properties you'd like to.

Your other option is to open the form's designer code file and do a find and replace on 'BackColor'.